# CSS transition causes lag

Tags: jquery, css, transition, gradient, lag

The transition inside of the box class causes the jQuery to lag, however if the page is refreshed a few times the lag will not appear. If you remove the transition, the lag will not appear at all, any way of keeping the CSS transition without the initial lag?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyaziz/Ukx4u/145/)

CSS:

```
html {
    background:url("http://www.phactr.com/css/img/background.jpg");
}
.box {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: .33s ease; 
}
.box:hover {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.over {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px) opacity(0.3);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#one").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#one, #two, #three").addClass("over", "blind");
        }, 10);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Please provide some code samples in your question, not just in a jsfiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by lag? I tried it on chrome and not seeing any abnormal behaviour. You have transition on `.box` and it is transitioning the opacity in 0.33 second, is this the lag you are referring to?

Comment: When the circle is clicked, the blur that is applied does not apply smoothly. It will apply smoothly if the transition is removed from the box class.

Comment: There are major visual issues on FF 25.0, but it doesn't look like you're trying to support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to prevent the transition when clicked but note that this will disable the transition when hovered again with the over class.

```
.over {
    transition: none;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px) opacity(0.3);
}
```

To keep the transition, you could do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#one").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#one, #two, #three").addClass("over", "blind").show().delay(100).css('transition', '0.33s ease');
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ukx4u/165/

The `.show()` is used to 'animated' then the delay and update transition. I am not unsure why you have the timeout function, it can be removed if it is not doing something I don't know of. I left it in because you had it in the original code

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I was looking for, I was hoping to keep the transition.

Comment: @Danny I updated, it's a bit messy. Using delay to delay the reset on transition. This keeps the transition after the class has been added

Comment: Thanks you pretty much sorted out the lag that I was seeing.